# Creating index in JS array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am generating a mysql query and the result is showing like this.

```
[
```

{
"brand": "Brand 1",
"channel": "TLP Channel",
"memo": 449
},
{
"brand": "Brand 1",
"channel": "C&C Channel",
"memo": 10
},
{
"brand": "Brand 1",
"channel": "GT Channel",
"memo": 1109
}
]

But I want to prepare the result array like the following :

```
[
{
    "Brand1" : [
        {
            "channel" : "TLP Channel",
            "Memo" : 449
        },
        {
            "channel" : "C&C Channel",
            "Memo" : 10
        },
        {
            "channel" : "GT Channel",
            "Memo" : 1109
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Brand2" : [
        {
            .....
        }
    ]
}
```

]

how can I prepare this with array map function in es6?

Comment: Include what you tried so far...

Comment: Hint: use an object to store `brand` name where the value is array of data, like: `map = { Brand1 => [], Brand2 => [] ...}`  then push data just by lookup key, like: `map[Brand1].push(<data>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, let me start by saying that the best way to store such a data is by keeping key uniform of the element objects. Right now you want to store the data in such a fashion that your resultant array has objects as elements, and each object has variable keys. This is not good practice.

Try doing something like

```
{
   "name": "Brand1",
    "items" : [
        {
            "channel" : "TLP Channel",
            "Memo" : 449
        },
        {
            "channel" : "C&C Channel",
            "Memo" : 10
        },
        {
            "channel" : "GT Channel",
            "Memo" : 1109
        }
    ]
}
```

instead of

```
{
    "Brand1" : [
        {
            "channel" : "TLP Channel",
            "Memo" : 449
        },
        {
            "channel" : "C&C Channel",
            "Memo" : 10
        },
        {
            "channel" : "GT Channel",
            "Memo" : 1109
        }
    ]
}
```

as each array element. With that out of the way, the solution to your code can also be done using `forEach()`, not just `map()`.

```
let result = [
  { brand: "Brand 1", channel: "TLP Channel", memo: 449 },
  { brand: "Brand 1", channel: "C&C Channel", memo: 10 },
  { brand: "Brand 1", channel: "GT Channel", memo: 1109 },
  
  { brand: "Brand 2", channel: "Something Channel", memo: 66 }
];

let final = [];

result.forEach(el => {    
  let i = final.findIndex(_obj => _obj.hasOwnProperty(el.brand));

  let _objToInsert = {
    channel: el.channel,
    memo: el.memo
  };

  if (i > -1) {
    // exists
    final[i][el.brand].push(_objToInsert);
  } else {
    // doesn't exist
    final.push({
      [el.brand]: [_objToInsert]
    });
  }
});

console.log(final)
```

[Find the working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5b4gxtzo/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can createa a `Map()` with an array of items based on the brands.

Then you can use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), and dynamic properties to transform your Map into your desired format.

```js
const currentFormat = [{
  "brand": "Brand 1",
  "channel": "TLP Channel",
  "memo": 449
}, {
  "brand": "Brand 1",
  "channel": "C&C Channel",
  "memo": 10
}, {
  "brand": "Brand 2",
  "channel": "GT Channel",
  "memo": 1109
}]

const itemsMap = new Map()

currentFormat.forEach(({
  brand,
  ...rest
}) => {
  if (itemsMap.has(brand)) itemsMap.get(brand).push(rest)
  else itemsMap.set(brand, [rest])
})

const newFormat = [...itemsMap].map(([brand, items]) => ({
  [brand]: items
}))

console.log(newFormat)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by `brand` and take the rest of the object as values.

1. A solution with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

   ```js
   const
       data = [{ brand: "Brand 1", channel: "TLP Channel", memo: 449 }, { brand: "Brand 1", channel: "C&C Channel", memo: 10 }, { brand: "Brand 1", channel: "GT Channel", memo: 1109 }],
       result = Array.from(
           data.reduce((m, { brand, ...o }) => m.set(brand, [...(m.get(brand) || []), o]), new Map),
           ([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v })
       );

   console.log(result);
   ```

   ```css
   .as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
   ```
2. A solution with an object for grouping

   ```js
   const
       data = [{ brand: "Brand 1", channel: "TLP Channel", memo: 449 }, { brand: "Brand 1", channel: "C&C Channel", memo: 10 }, { brand: "Brand 1", channel: "GT Channel", memo: 1109 }],
       result = Object
           .entries(data.reduce((r, { brand, ...o }) => {
               (r[brand] ??= []).push(o);
               return r;
           }, {}))
           .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }))

   console.log(result);
   ```

   ```css
   .as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
   ```